# Quaternion , DCM , Euler Angles and Rotation Matrix Differences and when to use?

Tags: rotations, quaternions

[Quaternion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) , DCM[Direction Cosine Matrix] , [Euler Angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) and Rotation Matrix  Differences and when to use ?

All of the above components can represent rotation , so when to use each of them , best approach and pros ,cons of each .

I've studied all of them but I feel I'm lost some how .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at my website:
noelhughes.net
there is a lot of material concerning these topics there.  In a nutshell:
1) Euler angles are very difficult to use mathematically.  They are ambiguous (there are 12 different formulations) and become singular at certain attitudes.  Their only positive aspect is that people are somewhat familiar with roll, pitch and yaw angles.
2) The DCM is complex to use but is stable.
3) Quaternions are simple to use, once they are understood, have no singularities.  The only downside is that quaternions are regarded as mysterious, almost magical, and impossible to be understood.  This view has been advanced by some "experts" in quaternions to enhance their (the experts') own stature.

Let me know if you have any questions after reviewing the material on my website.

Noel Hughes

Comment: Nothing mysterious about quaternions. Basically they can be viewed as a way to store rotation in the precomputed trigonometric form so that combining rotations becomes cheaper. Other than that from the user point of view the semantics are almost exactly the same as for rotation matrices.